# Set all categories to use Config Settings for 'Default Product Listing Sort By' option via SQL

Tags: magento2, database

I want to set all of my Magento 2 categories to 'Use Config Settings' for the 'Default Product Listing Sort By' within the Category Display Settings.

I don't want to do this manually as there are thousands of them.

What SQL command do I need to run to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this from the Magento forums. For those who may need it.

Get the attribute ID using the following (for me it was 66):

```
SELECT `attribute_code`,`attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'default_sort_by';
```

Then run the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = 66;

DELETE  FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = 66;
```

Comment: With this delete you also remove all 'default' settings. Might not be an issue in this specific case, since it will probably default to code specific setting. If you want to do this for, for example, name you should exclude store_id = 1:
`DELETE  FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 66 AND store_id != 0;`

Comment: OK - thanks for that